# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command error in Developer Command Prompt for VS2015

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to execute `npm install –g tsd` in Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.

But it returns

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

To solve this issue in Visual Studio 2017 (and above), make sure to install the **NodeJS tools** in the VS installer.

To launch it, go to **Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features**, scroll down to *Visual Studio 2017* and click **Change**.

Choose **Modify** in the installer.

Check the *Node.js development* checkbox and click **Modify** to complete the installation.

[image]

Comment: This is identical in VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

Download / Install NodeJS tools for Visual Studio; that'll fix the issue and give you intellisense among other benefits!

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools

Answer (score 2):

This solution is specifically for Visual studio code editor.
The easiest way to solve that, is to install plugin for `node.js` using VS code editor,
To do that follow the steps.

click on Extension Icon, and type in search box `node.js`, It will give you search result. 
Look for the `node.js Extension pack`.
[image]

It should look like the bellow screen, I have already install, the extension. That is why, the green install button is not visible, Just hit on install, once finished. Restart the VS code. now it should work for sure.
[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. I installed nodejs and npm on my system's command prompt and not the vscode's terminal. Not sure if this should make a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/. 'npm' may be unrecognized in Visual Studio 2017 and Win 10 OS when node.js package is not found. After installing node.js package, it will automatically add '..\nodejs' value in Environment variable 'PATH'. Once node.js package is installed, restart your Visual Studio 2017 to Rebuild your project again.